# How do I improve my last few questions?

Tags: discussion

I am going to delete my last few questions and ask that in blizzard forum instead.

Before that I need some feedback.

Here is my issue. I ask for things that's not obvious and not duplicate. However, people think it is.

For example, does cold damage always slow? Does that slowing count as chill? Does that proc with cold blood?

There are many answers and comments in this stack where people pretty much say either way. The correct answer that I can think of now is that yes cold weapons do 100% chill and slow and proc with cold blood all the time. That one is not obvious,.

Another issue is when I asked by how much monster health increase when BOTH monster power and number of player increase.

There are duplicate questions that ask how does those health increase when only ONE of them vary. No body address how it's computed when BOTH changes.

Yet people insist it's duplicate.

What am I missing?

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93527/with-monster-power-on-if-there-are-multiple-player-how-will-enemies-get-toughe#comment127730_93527

This one is upvoted, so  never mind :) [What exactly is Chilled in Diablo 3? Does cold damage chilled 100%?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90523/what-exactly-is-chilled-in-diablo-3-does-cold-damage-chilled-100)

Comment: You should add links to the questions you are talking about.

Comment: To be fair, I had mentioned that your MP question was something that hadn`t been addressed, and after you had explained it, it was a valid question.  The consensus seems to be that a complete answer on the duplicate question would include this info.

Comment: for what its worth i encountered a similar probelm a few months back, i dont neccesarily agree with the current protocol on these situations and a few others agree with my opinion. However, this is how its done right now so... just gotta roll with it. comment on answers that need to be updated and ask for updates, or bounty it yourself asking for an up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 7):

Those *questions* are duplicates. The problem is, the original question had an out of date answer.  The proper course of action in this situation is to provide an updated answer to the original question.

You could try offering a bounty to try to get an updated answer.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a good answer. The original question does not ask the same thing I asked. I asked how monster power and number of players interact. The original questions either ask how monster power increase power or how number of players interact.

Comment: The original question asks how much monster health increases as the member of players increases _period_. The scope of this includes monster power.

Comment: Somebody downvote your answer, I upvoted it. Sorry.

Comment: @JimThio Downvotes on the meta site indicate disagreement, not a lack of quality.  Similarly, upvotes indicate agreement.  Or so people keep telling me.

Comment: I updated my answer based on the information I could find, which is that number of players is applied after monster power.  This makes sense, otherwise MP10 with 4 players would be almost the same as MP10 with 1 player.